# Google safe browsing API doesn't work for me

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api

I started using Google Console API and I want to try Google safe browsing to check if a website contain a malware or no but it doesn't working for me this is my code:

```
public function check(){
    $url = 'http://www.facebokk.com';


    $apiKey = 'AI6k8kgflsgjhajjfldsjqldskqO2Iq5Ou0PE';
    $apiUrl = 'https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find?key='.$apiKey;

    $params = [
          'client' => [
              'clientId' => 'foobar',
              'clientVersion' => '1.2.3'
          ],
          'threatInfo' => [
                 "threatTypes" =>["MALWARE", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING"],
                "platformTypes" => ["WINDOWS"],
                 'threatEntryTypes' => ['URL'],
              'threatEntries' => [
                  [ 'url' => $url ]
              ]
          ]
      ];


    $ch = curl_init($apiUrl);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, [
                    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($params),
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                    'Content-Type: text/json'
                  ]
              ]);

    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($res, true);
}
```

This is the result :

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 Date: Thu, 27 Sep 2018 15:13:54 GMT Server: ESF Cache-Control: private X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39,35" Accept-Ranges: none Vary: Accept-Encoding Transfer-Encoding: chunked {}

Comment: can you elaborate on what exactly "doesnt work" ? Did you try it with pages including malware ? How did you test this? Do you get some sort of error / crash / stacktrace that you can show us ? "Doesnt work for me" is not very descriptive unfortunately :(

Comment: Provide code, results, expected results, and errors when asking a question.

Comment: please double check my question now

Comment: Please post expected result

Comment: i need a help please :(